# save T in inner extensions

Tags: c#, static-methods, typeof

I have two extensions:

```cs
public static TModel ObjectToModel<TModel>(this object source, string[] propsToExclude = null)
        where TModel : new()
{
   var dest = new TModel();
   source.CopyPropertiesToObject(dest, propsToExclude);
   return dest;
}

public static bool CopyPropertiesToObject<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest, string[] propsToExclude = null)
{
   propsToExclude = propsToExclude ?? new string[0];
   var sourceProps = typeof(T).GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>();
   var destProps = typeof(TU).GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(x => x.CanWrite && sourceProps.Any(s => s.Name == x.Name) && !propsToExclude.Any(e => e == x.Name));
   // code
 }
```

using:

```cs
source.CopyPropertiesToObject(dest); // fine
dest = source.ObjectToModel<TModel>(); // not work
```

This does not work because the `source` argument in the `ObjectToModel` method is of type `object` - so `var sourceProps = typeof(T).GetProperties()...` in the `CopyPropertiesToObject` method returns an empty list of properties.

How to change the `ObjectToModel<TModel>` extension to work properly?

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Can you provide some input examples?

Comment: @IanR.O'Brien In the `CopyPropertiesToObject` method that is being invoked by `ObjectToModel`, `typeof(T)` will return `System.Object`, instead of the actual type of the `source` variable. Thus, none of the properties will be copied.

Comment: `doesn't work because ..ObjectToModel<TModel>(this object source..` what does this line even mean? please use complete sentences.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary An edit by another user removed the emphasis on the type of the source argument.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin thanks for fixing it. that makes sense now :)

Comment: Why do you use `typeof(T)` instead of `source.GetType()`? GetType will give you the right typeof the object, regardless if you pass a base or derived object; in contrast, `typeof(T)` gives the base type and is therefore wrong by design.

Comment: @atlaste `typeof` gives you the statically known class, not the base class. That means it's resolved at compile time, rather than at runtime as `.GetType` is, and doesn't cost you anything. Since the class the OP wants to get properties from is known at compile time, it is better to use `typeof` along with a generic type parameter here.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Yes and no. Yes, you're right about the known class; I should have formulated that differently. However, getting a type translates to load token; `GetType` translates to a vtable lookup and a load token. Note that for value types, this could be a compile time construct (but probably isn't); for reference types it's most definitely not: load token will translate to something similar to a non-virtual call to GetType in that case. That said, it's irrelevant because getting properties using reflection will eat up the time. To avoid strange behavior, it's better to use GetType here.

Comment: So, looking at the differences -- using generics here doesn't make a lot of sense. .NET translates different generic reference types to the same assembler code, so you end up with something similar to a non-virtual GetType call anyways. Also, using generics can give you partial copies in this case, which is strange behavior. Therefore, I stand by my original conclusion: don't use generics in this case, and use GetType. The performance difference is negliable and it'll ensure you don't get strange behavior.

Comment: @atlaste I'm not really familiar with the IL being emitted, but from what you're saying it sounds like the work for `GetType` calls is done at runtime, so it isn't clear how this contradicts what I said. Regarding "strange behavior"; I would argue getting the statically known class results in *less* strange behavior, not more. If you have an interface implemented by some class from deep in the guts of some library, (`IEnumerable` is a good example), OP's code would reasonably expect to work against the interface they're aware of, not the implementation they're not aware of.

Comment: @atlaste Re: second comment; could you please elaborate? I don't understand what partial copies are (couldn't find on google either), or how the assembler code that is ultimately generated is relevant.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I'll put it all down in an answer below, that should clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's break it all down, shall we.

**What are we doing here?**

Apparently we're copying data from object Ao to object Bo. More precise: we're copying properties that intersect between type A to type B from object Ao to Bo. If a property is not in both types, we're not copying.

The assumption is that type A and type B are known compile-time. However:

> This does not work because the source argument in the ObjectToModel method is of type object

**What do we need?**

Basically we need runtime type information and we need to get property info (reflection). Note that there's no interface constraints here on the objects (we only know it can be instantiated) - basically this means that we're just using stuff that we know is in `object`. The only thing we don't have is the type.

Let's for the sake of argument add some code:

```
public class Named 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Named
{
  public int MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Named
{
  public int MyProp { get; set; }
  public int MySecondProp { get; set; }
}

// ...

Bar SomeMethod(Named source) 
{
  // code, code, code...
  return source.ObjectToModel<Bar>();
}
```

Question here is: what needs to happen? Should `MyProp` be copied?

Because of the way it's defined, I would think so. I would guess that's also why `object` is in the signature of the method in the first place.

**How to solve it?**

Well, if you do it like this, the only thing required is to get the type Foo so we can get the properties. Implementation is fairly simple:

```
public static TModel ObjectToModel<TModel>(this object source, string[] propsToExclude = null)
        where TModel : new()
{
   var dest = new TModel();
   CopyPropertiesToObject(source, dest, propsToExclude);
   return dest;
}


public static bool CopyPropertiesToObject(this object source, object dest, string[] propsToExclude = null)
{
   propsToExclude = propsToExclude ?? new string[0];
   var sourceProps = source.GetType().GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>();
   var destProps = dest.GetType().GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(x => x.CanWrite && sourceProps.Any(s => s.Name == x.Name) && !propsToExclude.Any(e => e == x.Name));
   // code
}
```

As you can see, I've completely removed the generic T from the thing. As a bonus, GetType uses a vtable lookup (inheritance) to get the most derived type of the `source` object, which is in this case `Foo` rather than `Named`.

**But but... isn't using generics good for performance?**

@AsadSaeeduddin made the remark that using typeof(T) is 'better' than GetType, because the information is known compile-time. Let's dive into the nitty gritty details here.

From a developer perspective it's true that we know what type and properties the object has if we pass it as generic template. However, that's not how the .NET compiler and runtime work.

Typeof is implemented in .NET as a `ldtoken` IL instruction, which basically gets a type token. The thing to get a token of is in this case the generic parameter `T`. At this point, you have to realize that generics are not C++ templates. More specifically, code is JIT'ted on a per-method basis, using the specifics of the constraints as the way to use and call methods. I'll explain with an example.

Say we have classes Name, Foo and Bar. All these classes have a (virtual / override) method 'GetName' that we call in a generic like this:

```
// Note: if Named was an interface, you should add 'class' as constraint!
public static string FindName<T>(this T source) where T : Named
{
  return source.GetName();
}
```

What happens under the hood is that the method is compiled by the JIT. At this point, we're sure that all instances of T are (equal size) pointers (hence the (hidden) `class` constraint) and that they are all instances of `Named`. It's not expanded like templates, so if we would literally translate this in the C++ equivalent, it'll work something like this:

```
static string FindName(Named* source)
{
  return source->GetName();
}
```

Actually, from this you can deduce that the compiled assembler code is actually no different from:

```
public static string FindName(this Named source)
{
  return source.GetName();
}
```

The only 'real' difference here with the question is the fact that you can use `typeof(T)` which translates to `ldtoken`. Obviously, this gives a different result for each `T`. At this point, .NET could have chosen 2 different implementations:

1. Re-compile the method for each different `T`.
2. Call `source.GetType()` non-virtual.

I won't go into details here how you can actually test this, but option (2) is what the .NET team decided to do. There is just one exception to this rule: if T is a value type, the impact on how the stack is handled for each type T differs (you have to put arguments on the stack, remember), which means the method has to be re-compiled. If you're still interested in how to test this, it's in one of my questions from a year back or so.

**So generics are just as fast as non-generics?**

No, not always. For example, consider the `IEquality<T>` interface:

```
bool Equals(T other);
```

A typical implementation of this is:

```
bool Equals(Foo other) { return other.MyProp == MyProp; }
```

If you consider the alternative (`object.Equals`), it's like this:

```
bool Equals(object other) { return other != null && other is Foo && ((Foo)other).MyProp == MyProp; }
```

Note that the difference in speed comes from the fact that we can assume much more, thereby simplifying the work the compiler has to do.

**Back to the question**

So let's get to the bottom line here:

- Using or not using generics here doesn't have any real impact on performance.
- Using generics gives you the type you're using, not the most derived type. From the signature, I'd expect the latter to be the objective.

Comment: very detailed answer. but then i ask to specify why you saved generic in CopyPropertiesToObject<TU> ??

Comment: Because you need the call to new, which is part of the constraint. That's the only reason basically.

Comment: ...oh oops, yes I should have removed that as well. You only need TModel.

Comment: The code you provided won't compile. You need to specify a `class/struct` constraint *or* a specific class, not both.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I wrote it from the top of my head in notepad, there's probably a few mistakes; the overall story is still correct though. The reason is that Named is already a class (so it cannot be a struct), so therefore it doesn't compile. Usually I use interfaces; if Named was an interface, it would have compiled. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the type of the object you're copying from as a type parameter. In the snippet below, I've added the `TSource` type parameter corresponding to the type of the first argument.

```
public static TModel ObjectToModel<TSource, TModel>(this TSource source, string[] propsToExclude = null)
    where TModel : new()
{
    var dest = new TModel();

    source.CopyPropertiesToObject(dest, propsToExclude);

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: What was the original issue and how does this solve it? I'm not doubting you - just looking for some clarity in addition to the code because I find this an interesting question.

Comment: @Asad Saeeduddin, i try it first and got an error "To use a generic method "DataMng.M.ObjectToModel<TSource,TModel>(TSource, string[])" requires two arguments of type"

Comment: @Qio How are you calling it?

Comment: @Asad Saeeduddin, like in topic: dest = source.ObjectToModel<TModel>();

Comment: @Qio You need to provide `TSource` as well. Whatever type the `source` variable is should be the first type argument, `TModel` should be the second.

Comment: @Asad Saeeduddin but i use `(**this** TSource source, ..)` instead ??

Comment: @Qio It doesn't matter. You either have to have a generic method for which all the type arguments can be inferred, or none of them are inferred and you have to provide them all. So do `source.ObjectToModel<TSource, TModel>(excludes)`.

Comment: @Asad Saeeduddin oh, it is not cost-effective solution(( TSource is mutable. now i use `var sourceProps = typeof(T) == typeof(Object) ? source.GetType().GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>() : typeof(T).GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>();` think this resolve well

Comment: @Qio I don't understand what you mean by `TSource` is mutable. How can a type be mutable?

Comment: @Qio Also, that ternary is useless since `typeof(T)` is always `Object` the way your code is structured right now.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin
`IList<IMyBase>(){new Type1(), new Type2()}.Select(x=> x..ObjectToModel<TModel>());` 
`typeof(T)` isn't `typeof(Object)` when use CopyPropertiesToObject() direct

Comment: @Qio Yeah, it's `IMyBase`, which is what you should provide as the type argument: `x.ObjectToModel<IMyBase, TModel>()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem was caused by boxing the source as an object rather than it's actual type.  So something like this will do the mapping.

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static TModel ObjectToModel<TSource, TModel>(this TSource source, string[] propsToExclude = null)
            where TModel : new()
        {
            var dest = new TModel();

            source.CopyPropertiesToObject(dest, propsToExclude);

            return dest;
        }

        public static bool CopyPropertiesToObject<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest, string[] propsToExclude = null)
        {
            try
            {
                propsToExclude = propsToExclude ?? new string[0];

                var sourceProps = typeof (T).GetProperties().Cast<PropertyInfo>().ToArray();
                var destProps =
                    typeof (TU).GetProperties()
                        .Cast<PropertyInfo>()
                        .Where(
                            x =>
                                x.CanWrite && sourceProps.Any(s => s.Name == x.Name) &&
                                propsToExclude.All(e => e != x.Name)).ToArray();

                foreach (var property in destProps)
                {
                    var sourceProperty = sourceProps.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == property.Name);
                    if (source != null)
                    {
                        var value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
                        property.SetValue(dest, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Scratch
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void PropertiesMapAsExpected()
        {
            var model = new Model {Id = 2, Name = "foo"};
            var viewModel = model.ObjectToModel<Model, ViewModel>();
            Assert.AreEqual(model.Id, viewModel.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(model.Name, viewModel.Name);
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int NotMapped { get; set; }
        }

        public class ViewModel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind that trying to dynamically map classes will often grow in complexity when you want to start mapping properties with different names, collections, nested objects and there are some performance penalties associated with reflection, though not as bad as they used to be.

You might want to check out [automapper](http://automapper.org/), it works on just about every version of .net, is highly optimized and configurable.

Comment: I try it first and got an error "To use a generic method "DataMng.M.ObjectToModel<TSource,TModel>(TSource, string[])" requires two arguments of type"